Build target stack was corrupted and contain other unfinished targets - VS 2022
I am using VS 2022 professional with .NET 6 WPF project, while opening the solution I get the exception like below
Recoverable System.InvalidOperationException: Build target stack was corrupted and contain other unfinished targets. Expect: 'DesignTimeMarkupCompilation', Actual: 'MarkupCompilePass1'. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Build.ErrorListLogger.Build_TargetFinished(Object sender, TargetFinishedEventArgs e)
I did uninstall VS 2022, Opening solution in Blend works but not in VS

Did you try backing it up, then deleting all the bin and obj directories?

Yes tried deleting the files, then re-opening solution, still same exception.

One thing that I observed was, when I open the solution in Blend then it works as expected. Also solution only works first time in VS 2022 after it was opened in Blend.
